# Forecast in R checking first prediction with AR (1) Model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a monthly inflation data. From 1999/01 to 2014/10.

I made an AR(1) model, with data from 1999/01 to 2007/12, which gaves me: Yt = 0.0057 + 0.6212Yt-1 ;

```
data<-read.table("C:/TimeSeries/Inflation/inflation.txt", header=T, dec=",")
data.ts <- ts(data, start=c(1999,01), freq=12)

time = window(data.ts, start=c(1999,01),end=c(2007,12))

inflarima<-Arima(time,order=c(1,0,0))
inflarima
```

---

As the theory says my first prediction should be: Et(Yt+1) = 0.0057 + 0.6212Yt ; The second:  0.0057 + 0.6212*0.0057 + (0.6212^2)*Yt and so on... Right ???

So, my first period prediction is january 2008, which gives a value of (0,0057 + 0,6212*Y2007,12 = (0,0057 + 0,6212*0.003790990 = **0,008054962988**) **0,008054962988**

---

## Running the prediction Code with Recursive Method

```
stat=c(2008,01) #First Prediction will be january 2008 
out_of_sample=window(data.ts,start=stat)  #out of sample data

recurs.pred1=ts(0,start=stat,end=c(2014,7),frequency=12) #Matrix to put the predictions through RECURSIVE METHOD

for (t in 1:(length(dado_de_fora))) {
  reg.recur1=Arima(window(time,end=c(2007,3+t)),c(1,0,0))
  recurs.pred1[t]=predict(reg.recur1,n.ahead=1)$pred #y chapeu de 1T2008, modelo Arma(1,1)
}
```

The values of my pedictions:

```
recurs.pred1[]    

           Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr           May        .......
2008 0.004556208 0.003796366 0.003965125     0.003948726  0.003681815   .......
```

---

Here starts the problem:

```
         Jan 
2008 0.004556208
```

HOW i got this value ???!! the right value supposed to be **0,008054962988** , am i Right?

These are the data: from: 1999/01 to 2014/07

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've committed several errors, both methodological and conceptual.

First error, I think, is from the lack of your understanding of AR(1): one step ahead forecast is not `a+bY{t}`, it is rather `a*(1-b)+b*Y{t}`. Your theory is wrong. Consult your textbook or documentation of the `arima` to clinch the matter. Thus, your forecast of Jan 2008 must be

```
> 0.0057*(1-0.6212) + 0.6212*0.003790990
[1] 0.004514123
```

Secondly, you have monthly based monthly inflation rates, so the argument in  `reg.recur1=Arima(window(time,end=c(2007, 3+t)),c(1,0,0))` must be `11+t`. (What is `Arima`?)

Finally, it is just plain wrong to fit inflation data in levels to AR(1). Oftentimes, it is suitable to fit the first difference of inflation, i.e. increase in inflation.

Following little example might help. I roughly followed your code.

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(20141221)
x <- arima.sim(n=108, list(ar=0.5))
data.ts <- ts(x, start=c(1999,01), freq=12)
time = window(data.ts, start=c(1999,01),end=c(2007,12))
inflarima <- arima(time, order = c(1, 0, 0)) #
inflarima$coef
#     ar1  intercept 
#0.4945659 0.2069526 
#1-step ahead forecast
0.4945659*time[108] + 0.2069526*(1-0.4945659)
#[1] 0.1147776
forecast(inflarima, h=1) #use forecast rather than predict. returns the same.
#         Point Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
#Jan 2008      0.1147776 -0.9938675 1.223423 -1.580749 1.810304
```

Comment: Yes my mistake. Thanks...i'll come back to books. Best regards